# this file dosent get created in a specific folder and dosent work at all

Tags: batch-file

I followed multiple guides online to find where is but I don't find where is the issue with this .bat file

```
@echo off

echo start "" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvFZjo5PgG0>%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\sys134.bat
```

with the sites I followed this must be correct

I want to make so a new batch file get created in startup file so every time someone open their PC they get rickrolled but the file doesn't look like getting into the startup files

Comment: `this must be correct` who said that? The most obvious issue is that the path contains spaces but isn't quoted

Answer (score 0):

This Path contains spaces :

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\sys134.bat
```

So this path must be quoted :

```
"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\sys134.bat"
```

---

And you can write it like this :

```bat
@echo off
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo start "" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvFZjo5PgG0
)>"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\sys134.bat"
```